# If a function is continuous on [a,b] such that $f(c)>0$, then there exists an open interval, $T,$ containing $c,$ such that $f(t)>0$ for all $t \in T$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, alternative-proof

I want to prove that if a function, $f,$ is continuous on [a,b] such that $f(c)>0$, then there exists an open interval, $T,$ containing $c,$ such that $f(t)>0$ for all $t \in T$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $\epsilon >0.$ Since $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ there is a point $t=c$ such that there exists a $\delta>0.$ By the delta-epsilon definition of continuity, |$f(t)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ for all $t$ such that |$t-c|<\delta.$ This is equivalent to $c-\delta < t < c + \delta$ which gives that $t \in (c-\delta,c+\delta).$ Thus, the open interval, $T$ exists.

I'm not sure if this is correct or if there is an alternative solution to this that would be better. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You are almost there, except you did not explain why $f(t) > 0$on the interval  $T$.

Comment: I think your proof has some issues. Firstly you don't use the assumption that $f(c) >0$ which is a very important assumption given what you are trying to prove. There are some other issues. For instance you should consider fixing a particular $\epsilon > 0$ and then try using $| f(t)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ to imply that $f(t) > 0$ for all $t$ in an appropriate interval.  There are also some places where the language you are using is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to specify your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ accordingly. Let us pick $\epsilon = \frac{f(c)}{2}$ (this is a quite standard way if you know the function value at one point and want to prove this type of results). Take, the corresponding $\delta$, whose existence is guaranteed by continuity, such that:
$$
|t-c|<\delta \implies |f(t)-f(c)|<\epsilon
$$
which implies that for every $t \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $f(t)>\frac{f(c)}{2}>0$.